# Filling a ruby array with a default object

Tags: ruby

Let's say I have a class Counter in ruby, defined as

```
class Counter
    attr_accessor :starting_value
    def initialize(starting_value)
        @starting_value = starting_value
    end

    def tick
        @starting_value = @starting_value + 1
    end
end
```

and I want to fill an array with that object, using a default parameter, like this:
`counter_arr = Array.new(5, Counter.new(0))`

This is almost what I want, except that I now have an array that contains the same instance of a counter 5 times, instead of an array of 5 new counters. IE when I run the code

```
counter_arr = Array.new(5, Counter.new(0)) 
counter_arr[0].tick
counter_arr.each do |c|
    puts(c.starting_value)
end
```

I output

```
1
1
1
1
1
```

instead of

```
1
0
0
0
0
```

I was wondering, what is the "ruby-esque" way to initialize an array with multiple new instances of an object?

Comment: Don't forget syntax features like `@starting_value += 1`. That's usually less verbose and avoids typographical errors.

Comment: This code is pretty much line-for-line identical to the example in the ["Common gotchas"  section of the docs for `Array::new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-c-new-label-Common+gotchas) which answer this very question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the first major stumbling blocks people encounter when learning Ruby if they're unfamiliar with a language that uses object reverences pervasively is how these work.

An array is a collection of references to zero or more other objects. These objects are not necessarily unique, and in some cases they are all identical. You are creating such an object here:

```
counters = Array.new(5, Counter.new(0))
```

This creates a singular Counter object and populates all 5 slots of the array with it. This comes about because arguments to methods are evaluated once before the method is called. You can test this:

```
counters.map(&:object_id)
```

That returns the unique object ID for each object in the array. They'll be random values, each process is different, but they will be identical.

The way to fix this is to use the block initializer:

```
counters = Array.new(5) do
  Counter.new(0)
end
```

That doesn't insert the same object, but the result of evaluating that block each time, and since that initializes a new Counter object, the objects will be unique.

One way to tidy this up is to adjust your `Counter` object to have a sane default:

```
class Counter
  def initialize(initial = nil)
    @value = initial.to_i
  end

  def tick
    @value += 0
  end
end
```

This has the advantage of accepting arbitrary values, even those that aren't necessarily the right type. Now `Counter.new('2')` will work with that value being converted automatically. This is the fundamental principle of Duck Typing. If it can give you a number, it's as good as a number.

Comment: thanks! That code was literally the first 21 lines of ruby I've ever written, so I appreciate all improvements.

Comment: Hope that works out for you. Seems like you're already off and running, which is good to see.

Comment: Very clear answer. Perhaps `def initialize(initial=0); @value = initial; end`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I try to default to `nil` as sometimes values of that sort sneak through inadvertently. `= 0` gives a sort of false confidence that it will be forced to `0` by default, but it's only `0` if the argument is not specified, a subtle but important distinction.

Comment: You don't want an "inadvertent" `nil` to raise an exception?

Comment: In this case `nil.to_i` produces the desired results, it's acceptable. Likewise for `options = nil` where it expects a Hash if populated. In other cases `nil` could be harmful and you do want it to do that. Depends on the situation.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
counter_arr = Array.new(5) { Counter.new(0) }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
counter_arr = ([-> { Counter.new(0) }] * 5).map &:call
```

Comment: That's a pretty crazy solution, but it is at least novel.

Comment: I think the other answers provide cleaner solutions, but I am still curious as to what is going on here

Comment: It is Ursus's answer expressed inside-out.

Comment: Well, first of all I upvoted @tadman’s answer, and then I recalled that I’m the “just-out-of-curiosity-clown” here. So: the `Counter` constructor is wrapped withing a `proc` to delay it’s execution, than an array of size 1 is created out of this `proc`, then this array is being spread to have 5 elements using `Array#*` and finally it’s mapped to actual counters by invoking `proc`s.